# How do I match header in different sheets and copy/paste the second row if there's a match?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel document with two different Sheets. 
Sheet 1 has many columns with header names and blank rows.
Sheet 2 has some of these columns with exact header names and an entry in the 2nd Row.

I want to make a macro that will look through all the column headers in Sheet 2 and find their corresponding match in Sheet1. When the match is found, I need to copy the entry in Row 2 of the Sheet2 header into the matching header of sheet1. 
Some entries in Sheet1 will not have matches and will remain blank.

## My 2 sheets currently:

### Sheet1

```
apple   | orange | mango  | grape  | banana
------------------------------------------
[BLANK] |[BLANK] |[BLANK] |[BLANK] | [BLANK]
```

### Sheet2

```
orange | mango  | banana 
--------------------------
yumm   | yuck   | maybe
```

## What I want after Macro is run:

### Sheet1

```
apple   | orange | mango  | grape  | banana
------------------------------------------
[BLANK] |yumm    |yuck    |[BLANK] | maybe
```

I am learning VBA, about 2 weeks in. I am having trouble with getting my program to do this. I have seen similar questions but they usually match one item in one column only not multiple names in multiple columns. The codes I have tried have not done anything like what I need.

Also, This has to be done as a macro or function since the program will be sent to a user that needs this to be already done automatically. I think that doing VLOOKUP would not work here since I will not know the number of columns in either sheet until the user enters them in which case the program will automatically populate the row 2 of the matching ones. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to determine the column number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it, assuming sheet names are `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

```
Sub colLookup()

Dim ShtOne As Worksheet, ShtTwo As Worksheet
Dim shtOneHead As range, shtTwoHead As range
Dim headerOne As range, headerTwo As range

Set ShtOne = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ShtTwo = Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lastCol As Long

'get all of the headers in the first sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtOne.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
Set shtOneHead = ShtOne.range("A1", ShtOne.Cells(1, lastCol))

'get all of the headers in second sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtTwo.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
Set shtTwoHead = ShtTwo.range("A1", ShtTwo.Cells(1, lastCol))

'actually loop through and find values
For Each headerTwo In shtTwoHead
    For Each headerOne In shtOneHead
        If headerTwo.Value = headerOne.Value Then
            headerOne.Offset(1, 0).Value = headerTwo.Offset(1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next headerOne
Next headerTwo


End Sub
```

EDIT: as per discussion in comments, a copy and paste method was desired. This keeps the cells as a list drop down, although I do not think the drop down will still work. If that was not desired, it is possible to change the `xlPasteAll` to other formats, such as `xlPasteValues`. Others are listed in [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx).

```
Sub colLookup()

Dim ShtOne As Worksheet, ShtTwo As Worksheet
Dim shtOneHead As range, shtTwoHead As range
Dim headerOne As range, headerTwo As range

Set ShtOne = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ShtTwo = Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lastCol As Long

'get all of the headers in the first sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtOne.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
Set shtOneHead = ShtOne.range("A1", ShtOne.Cells(1, lastCol))

'get all of the headers in second sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtTwo.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
Set shtTwoHead = ShtTwo.range("A1", ShtTwo.Cells(1, lastCol))

'actually loop through and find values
For Each headerTwo In shtTwoHead
    For Each headerOne In shtOneHead
        If headerTwo.Value = headerOne.Value Then
            headerTwo.Offset(1, 0).Copy
            headerOne.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next headerOne
Next headerTwo


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did exactly what I needed. One question though, This works for cells with values in it. It did not work with drop down lists that were in row 2 of sheet 2. How can I modify the code to Paste value instead of setting them equal to one another?                `For Each headerTwo In shtTwoHead
    For Each headerOne In shtOneHead
        If headerTwo.Value = headerOne.Value Then
            headerOne.Offset(1, 0).Value = headerTwo.Offset(1, 0).Value 'CAN I COPY AND PASTE? HERE INSTEAD?
        End If
    Next headerOne
Next headerTwo`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I modified my made up data to have drop down lists in the second row of sheet two, and the code still matched up the values. Are there any errors that are thrown, or is it just not matching the data and leaving the cells blank?

Comment: @KatyTorres I am adding a new code in addition to what I have up there. Please see above.

Comment: No errors are thrown. It works perfect for all the values so I am sure the headers are matching fine, it just does not populate the 2nd row if it happens to be a drop down and not a simple value. I will look into this and let you know what resolves it.

Comment: @PartyHatPanda How can I make it go through all the rows instead of only copying the first row?

Comment: @2by inside the inner loop where I am was having the offset in place, you can capture the last row of the column and loop through from the start row to the last row. Let me know if you need assistance with that, but there are a lot of examples on that.

Comment: @PartyHatPanda I tried a for loop after getting the last row. For some reason it did not work, it still only took the first row but now it didn’t put the values in the right columns. An example would be highly appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I was looping the wrong value. Everything works - thank you