# Excel VBA Copy Column of data with matching Cell data

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to find a solution to this issue but the terminology used doesn't quite give my searches the results I am after and I am not familiar enough to adapt VBA to my needs. My intention is to copy a whole column of data in a single sheet to a different column that matches a cell in the same row in the same sheet. Let me try to explain, my data would look like below until I run the VBA:

```
apple   | orange | mango  | apple  | banana
------------------------------------------
1       |[BLANK] |[BLANK] |[BLANK] | [BLANK]  
2       |[BLANK] |[BLANK] |[BLANK] | [BLANK]  
3       |[BLANK] |[BLANK] |[BLANK] | [BLANK]
```

I would want the VBA to match the row (not necessarily the top row, it would be on the 11th in my current sheet) and copy the entire column over leaving me with the example. There should only be one column match.

```
apple   | orange | mango  | apple  | banana
------------------------------------------
1       |[BLANK] |[BLANK] |1       | [BLANK]  
2       |[BLANK] |[BLANK] |2       | [BLANK]  
3       |[BLANK] |[BLANK] |3       | [BLANK]
```

I found the following code which works in matching the header/cell data then copying the row below it, however it only copies the first row below the "header" row and would like it to loop down the rows until the bottom of the data.

```
Sub colLookup()
Dim ShtOne As Worksheet, ShtTwo As Worksheet
Dim shtOneHead As range, shtTwoHead As range
Dim headerOne As range, headerTwo As range

Set ShtOne = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ShtTwo = Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lastCol As Long

'get all of the headers in the first sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtOne.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
Set shtOneHead = ShtOne.range("A1", ShtOne.Cells(1, lastCol))

'get all of the headers in second sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtTwo.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
Set shtTwoHead = ShtTwo.range("A1", ShtTwo.Cells(1, lastCol))

'actually loop through and find values
For Each headerTwo In shtTwoHead
    For Each headerOne In shtOneHead
        If headerTwo.Value = headerOne.Value Then
            headerTwo.Offset(1, 0).Copy
            headerOne.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next headerOne
Next headerTwo
End Sub
```

From here: [How do I match header in different sheets and copy/paste the second row if there's a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255708/how-do-i-match-header-in-different-sheets-and-copy-paste-the-second-row-if-there)

So in other terms match A1 on Sheet1 with B1 - F1 on sheet 1 and copy A2 - A10 to the matching row so for example E2 - E10.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, you just need to set your cursor or active cell to be the first header of your data table, since you said that its not always on the first row.

```
Sub testy()
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, i As Long 'declare limits and loop variables
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range       'declare cell reference variables

Set cell = Range("C11")               'set the starting point, eg.: C11
lr = cell.End(xlDown).Row             'find the last row
lc = cell.End(xlToRight).Column       'find the last column

'set the range to be copied
Set rng = Range(Cells(cell.Row + 1, cell.Column), Cells(lr, cell.Column))

'loop through the headers looking for a match
'when a match is found, paste rng directly under the header
For i = rng.Column + 1 To lc
    If Cells(cell.Row, i).Value = cell.Value Then
        rng.Offset(0, i - cell.Column).Value = rng.Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This works well, however is it possible to declare a cell to start at rather than activate a cell, would prefer not to leave that to chance. So say Cell C11 then start from there? So checking D11, E11, etc.

Comment: @donttakemeseriously I made an edit to account for this, I also commented the code. I didn't hard set the starting position because you mentioned that it's not always the same

Comment: that's perfect, sorry I wasn't clear, the row was static but not necessarily located on the first row was what I was trying to say. How easy would it be once that completes to copy the column to the right back to the C11 column? So C11 matches and copies the column to E11, then takes F11 and copies it back to C11?

Each column is a weekly check with pre-defined values so want to record and prepare for the next list of checks in one go. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: You just gotta put a line similar to the one on my loop to assing the new value on `rng.Value`, and offset it by +1 so it takes the column to the right

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
Option Base 1 'array will start at 1 instead of 0
Sub colLookup()
Dim ShtOne As Worksheet, ShtTwo As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr() 'we will work with arrays
Dim StringMatch$ '$ means "as string"
Dim i%, j%

    Set ShtOne = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ShtOne
        Set rng = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'set the range as all the current region
    End With
arr = rng 'save the region into the array

'Now it's time to work only with the array. Is the best way to work while coding on VBA, try to don't use excel formulas

'Search the the header of (1,1) in the first row. In your case "apple"
StringMatch = arr(1, 1)
'now it's time to check all the columns with a for - next loop. LBound means lower bound of the array and UBound the Upper Bound.
'In VBA arrays, UBound and LBound always works with the first dimension of the array. So, as we have a two dimension array and we want to navigate thru the columns, it's necessary to aks for the "transposed" array
For i = LBound(Application.Transpose(arr)) + 1 To UBound(Application.Transpose(arr)) 'lbound+1 because first column is the original. You can use for i = 2 to ubound(...)
    If arr(1, i) = StringMatch Then
            For j = 2 To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print j
                arr(j, i) = arr(j, 1)
            Next j
        i = UBound(Application.Transpose(arr)) 'this line code is to stop the loop if you only want ONE copy
    End If
Next i

'Now the values are stored in you array. It's time to print out to your Excel
With ShtOne
    rng = arr
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This also functions as I'd like, as per my comment for the other code, how would I declare a specific cell to match, C11 for example example?